# Amazon API Gateway for .NET core vs implementing own API gateway?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are planning to create our own API gateway that will have:

1. Microservice discovery mechanism
2. Handling parallel requests
3. Taking care of authorization

We have most of our APIs already written in .NET 4.5 (nearly 1000 APIs) and I recently read [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1178781/Serverless-Architecture-using-Csharp-and-AWS-Amazo) that we can use Amazon API gateway with .NET core.

I am now wondering if it makes sense to rediscover the wheel when Amazon is already offering similar service? What could be pros and cons of using Amazon API gateway vs creating own API gateway?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question but rather a business question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO no, it doesn't make any sense to re-create what you can buy for a few pennies, from a team of people who are probably smarter than you (and me) and are constantly improving and monitoring what they have provided.

If the API gateway does what you want, you'd be crazy to write your own - your solution is unlikely to be better, it will almost certainly cost more, and sooner or later you will get tired of supporting it yourself.

Comment: Does Amazon have any plan to launch SDK for .NET 4.x too?

Comment: I am pretty sure they already have a .net 4.x sdk: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Comment: How is the support of parallel request in Amazon API gateway? Can we submit multiple .NET API request to API gateway and it returns back a response for each one (with the execution of each call in parallel)?

Comment: @maverick parallel (concurrent) requests are not a problem.  Each request is handled in its own Lambda container, with the number of containers automatically managed.  The *default* limit is 10000 simultaneous (no kidding) requests at the gateway, and 1000 or more concurrent lambda containers running functions at any instant in time. (The gateway can handle things other than Lambda, and also does pre- and post- request processing before and/or after the Lambda invocation starts/ends.) You can ask for higher limits.